# The meaning of "Who should find it but you?"

Tags: sentence-meaning, questions, punctuation

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (2002) Extended*, Tom Riddle says to Harry Potter about diary:

> Tom Riddle: Still, the power of the diary began to scare her. She tried to dispose of it in the girls' bathroom. And then who should find it **but you?**

Why question mark kept after "you" instead of after "it"?

Why not like this:

> And then who should find it? You Harry?

Comment: Why would you think the question mark should stay after "it"? The question mark *always* goes at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Who should ... but ..." is a set phrase that indicates that some [serendipitous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/serendipitous) has happened.

Here is some dialogue that illustrates its use:

> "We were sitting in the pub talking about our boss when who should walk in but our boss!"